# Change Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME to always be 1

Tags: android, android-timepicker, android-timer

I want Android apps to believe that Automatic Time Zone is set to ON even though it actually is not. I read that Automatic Time Zone is detected using Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME variable, which returns value 1 if Automatic Time Zone is ON and value 0 if Automatic Time Zone is OFF.
This variable is read using the below line

```
Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME)
```

I read that this variable can only be set by a System App. Is there a way to change this variable somehow? Can I write an application that allows me to change this variable? Can this be done by rooting the android device.

Comment: ...........COV?

Comment: If you want your apps to 'believe' that the setting is set to on even when it's not then simply don't read the settings and assume it is on..

Comment: @akash93 By "My Apps" I meant the apps that I use and not some App, that I am making. Edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The most commonly suggested solution is to use `Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 1)`. You will end up seeing this message in logcat, though:

```
Setting auto_time has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, value is unchanged.
```

According to the Android documentation, apps cannot modify these settings.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global

> Global system settings, containing preferences that always apply identically to all defined users. Applications can read these but are not allowed to write; like the "Secure" settings, these are for preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values.

These settings are read-only unless your app is installed as a system app or is signed by the manufacturer of the device that it is running on.

Most people end up rooting their device but there is an alternative. Device Owner apps can modify global system settings through a different API.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#setGlobalSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

You would do it like so:

```java
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), DeviceAdminReceiver.class);
dpm.setGlobalSetting(component, Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, enable ? "1" : "0");
```

This alternative is mostly suitable for homebrew apps and proprietary Android-based products because the device cannot have user accounts. Play Store will not install apps as Device Owner, it must be done manually.

Here is how to do it with ADB:

https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/cookbook#dev-setup

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 1)` to set the value from your app.

You need to have the `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission though.

Comment: How to get write permissions? Isn't that available only to system apps?

Comment: You need to create an app and request that permission. User apps can have the permission as well.

Comment: That piece of code always returns false on user apps, even if `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission is granted, thus it doesn't work. 
Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html "Global system settings, containing preferences that always apply identically to all defined users. Applications can read these but are not allowed to write"